# Android: show chromcast media controller NOT in full screen

Tags: android, chromecast

Per the chromcast android docs [found here](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/design_checklist/sender#sender-expanded-controller), an expanded media controller is actually provided by the api.

The issue is that I don't want a full screen controller.  I'm looking to set the controller inside the smaller play window in portrait mode (like in youtube).  Any clues on where I can find documentation on doing this?

Here's the image example from the docs:

[image]

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to define your own activity, based on what you'd like it to look like, and set that in your [CastMediaOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/CastMediaOptions), to be opened when needed. If you do that, you then need to implement the required functionality yourself but given the [UIMediaController](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/uicontroller/UIMediaController) and [ControlButtonsContainer](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/widget/ControlButtonsContainer), it shouldn't be too difficult to do that.

Comment: you definitely pointed me in the right direction!  Thank you!